# Web Application with Storage using Azure

Tags: c#, node.js, azure, azure-storage

I am working on using Azure to maintain a web application that will allow me to store information into a storage system through a web interface. I would then like to query the information from that storage system using a client application. I noticed that there are a variety of technologies that can be used to accomplish this, such as node.js, C#, php and python. I am confused about how to proceed. I tried to create a website on Azure using Microsoft WebMatrix which uses Nodejs, and I was able to create a simple express site. But, I could not see any options for a storage element to interface with node.js. I am not looking to spend too much time on making a custom Web UI, but would rather like to use some sort of template for the UI. Which technologies would be best to proceed based on my requirements?

Thanks!

Comment: How much time are you willing to spend learning? Do you seek a very quick solution to a limited-size problem, or do you want to become a well-versed web-developer?

Comment: I am willing to spend a considerable amount of time learning. I am looking to become a well-versed web developer. I am not looking to just hack something together

Comment: In terms of creating the UI for the website I am not really interested in spending too much on it though. If possible, I would like to use some sort of template for it.

Comment: If you're comfortable with using the Microsoft platform you should probably look into the typical, well-integrated Microsoft stack: IIS, ASP.NET MVC, C#, SQL Server. That's how the big .NET web apps are built, and it is nice to use. WebMatrix is for beginners and very small projects. NodeJs is redundant and not helpful to learn if you already know how to use ASP.NET properly.

Answer (score 0):

There is a node version of the Storage Client library available in the Azure SDK which you can find [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-node). This library will enable you to interact with Storage resources such as Blobs, Tables and Queues which might be useful for your application. There are also some node getting started tutorials available [here](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/services/storage/#node) which sound like they might also be useful.

You should also track the [Windows Azure Storage Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2014/05/16/microsoft-azure-storage-client-library-and-tooling-updates-teched-2014.aspx) as updates are coming for the node client library as well.

Jason